# Something wrong with my switch condition?

Tags: javascript

Here I try to display an image message from actionCable response.

```
function displayCableMessage(data) {
  var cableMessage = '';
  var profileBlock =  '<span class="chat-img1 ' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'pull-right' : 'pull-left') + '">' +
                        '<img alt="Kiet Ta" class="img-circle" ' + 'src="' + displayAvatar(data["user"]["avatar_url"]) + '">' +
                      '</span>';

  var messageListItem = '<li class="' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'left ' : 'right ') + 'clearfix ' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'admin-chat ' : '') + '">'
  switch(data['transaction_message']['activity']) {
    case 'attach_image':
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageImage(data) + '</li>';
      console.log(cableMessage);
    case 'attach_file':
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageFile(data) + '</li>';
    default:
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageNormal(data) + '</li>';
  };
  console.log('final' + cableMessage);
  console.log(data['transaction_message']['activity']);
  return cableMessage;
}
```

I use console.log to display the cableMessage with the switch statement as below. I think that console.log(cableMessage) number one and number two - console.log('final' + cableMessage) should be the same (except 'final' of course). However, this is the result. 
cableMessage number 1:

```
<li class="right clearfix ">
  <span class="chat-img1 pull-left">
    <img alt="Kiet Ta" class="img-circle" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xtaypro-dev/paperclip/attachments/original/9382_image.png?1520472303">
  </span>
  <div class="chat-content me clearfix">
    <p>
      <a class="img" data-fancybox="gallery " href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xtaypro-dev/paperclip/attachments/original/10152_SAVED-20180327_0451_46844.jpg">
        <img style="height:130px;" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xtaypro-dev/paperclip/attachments/original/10152_SAVED-20180327_0451_46844.jpg">
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

cableMessage number 2:
final

```
<li class="right clearfix ">
  <span class="chat-img1 pull-left">
    <img alt="Kiet Ta" class="img-circle" src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/xtaypro-dev/paperclip/attachments/original/9382_image.png?1520472303">
  </span>
  <div class="chat-content me clearfix">
    <p>10152_SAVED-20180327_0451_46844.jpg</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Why the whole  tag disappeared in number 2? Also, the last console.log
`console.log(data['transaction_message']['activity']);` is equal 'attach_image', matches the first case of switch statement. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're getting both `console.log(cableMessage);` and `console.log('final' + cableMessage);` in your logs, and it's doing the default case, right? that's what the code as written should be doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add `break`s to ensure jumping out of the switch and stop processing other cases:

```
function displayCableMessage(data) {
  var cableMessage = '';
  var profileBlock =  '<span class="chat-img1 ' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'pull-right' : 'pull-left') + '">' +
                        '<img alt="Kiet Ta" class="img-circle" ' + 'src="' + displayAvatar(data["user"]["avatar_url"]) + '">' +
                      '</span>';

  var messageListItem = '<li class="' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'left ' : 'right ') + 'clearfix ' + (isFromCurrentUser(data) ? 'admin-chat ' : '') + '">'
  switch(data['transaction_message']['activity']) {
    case 'attach_image':
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageImage(data) + '</li>';
      console.log(cableMessage);
      break;
    case 'attach_file':
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageFile(data) + '</li>';
      break;
    default:
      cableMessage = messageListItem + profileBlock + messageNormal(data) + '</li>';
      break;
  };
  console.log('final' + cableMessage);
  console.log(data['transaction_message']['activity']);
  return cableMessage;
}
```

Comment: You are right. It fixes my problem. Thanks a lot.